# ASSERT doesn't works in the application VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I have a problem with builded in debug mode application. I build this application in VS 2015. When I run it, ASSERT inside functions doesn't executed. I suspect that this is problem in some of VS 2015 settings, or maybe there are problems with windows kits or SDK. 
Maybe somebody faced with the same situation?
I use Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: Would you please share us the latest information? Could you get useful information from Weiwei's suggestion? If not, would you please share the project type you were created? How did you use the Assert in your functions?

Answer (score 0):

> When I run it, ASSERT inside functions doesn't executed.

Please make sure you are select "Debug" in Visual Studio 2015 when you press F5 to run this application. Because the Debug.Assert() function only works when you debug your application. If you choose Release and start run your application, the Debug.Assert() function will not be executed.

[image]

In addition, please create a new project and add Debug.Assert() function to check whether this issue only occurs in this one specific project or all projects.

If only this specific project has this issue, please check the bool value in Debug.Assert() function, make sure it is false. If it is true, this function will not be executed.

If all projects has this issue, please check your Visual Studio 2015 version, confirm it has installed the latest update and check whether there has any third part VS packages installed that affect the Visual Studio debugger. You could run your Visual Studio 2015 in safe mode to verify this.